# Volatile e otimização

Tags: c, desempenho, assembly, gcc, volatile

Eu estou estudando sobre o qualificador de tipo `volatile` na linguagem C, e fiz um teste.

Na imagem anexada temos a comparação de dois programas escritos em C. O da esquerda possui uma variável sem o volatile e o da direita é o mesmo programa mas com uma variável volatile.

Abaixo de cada programa, temos o código Assembly respectivo.

Como não sei muito de Assembly, a minha dúvida é: o teste lógico do `while (valor == 666)` foi otimizado no código Assembly da esquerda?

Como o valor da variável `valor` nunca é alterado no código, eu imagino que o compilador possa otimizar o teste lógico ao substituir `valor == 666` por `1`. Isso está certo?

[image: códigos comparando]

Comment: Quais flags vc usou para compilar isso?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta; mas para gerar o código Assembly eu utilizei: gcc -S programa.c

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` não é um mecanismo de otimização, e portanto quando o usou nada foi otimizado.

Quando você usa essa palavra chave está dizendo que essa informação pode ser mudada à qualquer momento sem seu estrito controle, então o que o compilador fez foi adicionar uma instrução extra, portanto ficará mais lento, e sua função foi proteger o dado que está sendo usado na comparação.

Se o que está dizendo que que ali pode ter uma alteração que você não tem controle está justamente mandando não otimizar porque a otimização poderia afetar isso erroneamente.

Se deseja alguma otimização, então mande otimizar, faça com a *flag* `-O3` para obter o máximo de otimização de velocidade. Nada garante quais otimizações serão feitas porque a linguagem não exige nada disso, mas é provável que seja bem simplificado. O `volatile` impedirá a otimização.

Seu código no GCC usando `O3`:

```
.LC0:
        .string "volatile"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
.L2:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        jmp     .L2
```

Veja [no **Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/qWhVXa).

No Clang:

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    RBP
        mov     RBP, RSP
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     EDI, .L.str
        xor     AL, AL
        call    printf
        jmp     .LBB0_1

.L.str:
        .asciz   "volatile"
```

Veja [no **Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/MYr5Cx).

No MSVC a otimização não é feita no momento até onde pude observar.

No ARM usando GCC:

```
main:
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -32]!
        mov     x29, sp
        str     x19, [sp, 16]
        adrp    x19, .LC0
        add     x19, x19, :lo12:.LC0
.L2:
        mov     x0, x19
        bl      printf
        b       .L2
.LC0:
        .string "volatile"
```

Veja [no **Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/2Xcjig).

Comment: Certo, mas no programa da esquerda, o compilador alterou o teste lógico (valor == 999) para 1 (já que o valor da variável nunca se altera)? Ou não? Se não, por quê?

Comment: Não sei que alteração você quer que faça ou que está falando, não existe alteração alguma alguma.

Comment: A pergunta é: no código da esquerda, o compilador poderia substituir o teste lógico (para fins de otimização) simplesmente por 1? Já que a variável "valor" não possui o volatile e seu valor nunca é alterado.

Comment: Poderia, depende de como mandou compilar, no caso não fez.

Comment: Legal! Como posso compilar visando otimizar esse código para desaparecer com o teste lógico? Devo utilizar essa tal flag?

Comment: Sim, mas otimizações não são garantidas, poder não é dever de fazer.

Comment: Entendi. Quando eu vou compilar pelo GCC eu utilizo: gcc -o <executavel> <programa>.c. Você sabe se assim ele já pode otimizar?

Comment: Poder pode, mas é menos provável porque não está deliberadamente mandando otimizar. Pode usar `-o3` que é a otimização máxima e ainda assim não otimizar. Em tese se um compilador tiver uma *flag* que manda fazer especificamente essa otimização ainda assim, a não ser que esteja documentado pelo compilador que ele especificamente garanta que fará, ele pode ou não fazer.

Comment: Acho que agora ficou mais claro. Muito obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1):

Editando o seu código um pouco para deixar a otimização mais clara.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int valor = 666;
    return (valor == 666) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Compilando no GCC com a flag `-O3`.

```
main:
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

Agora compilando o mesmo programa com `volatile` e `-O3`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    volatile int valor = 666;
    return (valor == 666) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

```
main:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], 666
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        cmp     eax, 666
        sete    al
        movzx   eax, al
        ret
```

Volatile não é um otimizador e faz exatamente o contrário, pois impõe restrições ao compilador.

Comment: Interessante. O que estou com dúvida é: no código da esquerda, o compilador poderia substituir o teste lógico (para fins de otimização) simplesmente por 1? Já que a variável "valor" não possui o volatile e seu valor nunca é alterado.

Comment: Provavelmente sim. Depende muito do compilador. 
Por exemplo, se esse código fosse C++, o MSVC provavelmente iria deixar essa otimização passar batido, enquanto que o CLANG quase que com certeza iria otimizar. Esse tipo de otimização não está no standard então não é obrigatória. 
Uma maneira melhor de sinalizar para o compilador que vc deseja ter essa otimização seria marcar as variáveis como constantes (C), ou usar `constexpr` para fazer essa verificação somente uma vez durante a compilação (C++).

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pela atenção!